# How to specify logging format for libraries in Python (dependencies)

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I am using the Python logging library and my app uses a few other external libraries.

```
logging.basicConfig(
    filename="/log/output.log", 
    level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
)
```

I am noticing logs from my app are formatted in the format specified above, but not the logs outputted by the external libs.  They appear without the formatting.  How can I force the logs to adhere to the parent logger format?  The logs all are routed to the same file.

Good log

```
2020-07-17 16:38:51,677 - app.somapp- INFO - event=retry user_id=123
```

Dependency log (not formatted)

```
INFO:dependency.logger, caller="/litle.py:1", category="Decline", user_id="123"
```

Answer (score 1):

Python logging module works in a hierarchical way by default. Refer [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate).

Ensure the following 2 things.

1. In the library, Logger.propogate should be True or simply not set.
2. In your code, the piece of code that sets the format should be executed before importing any library module that has 'import logging' in it.